# ng-disabled is being set correctly, but not affecting HTML disabled attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to en/disable a button when a dropdown has a particular string in it.

#### HTML

```
<select ng-change="checkType()" ng-options="sth in sth for things"></select>
<input ng-disabled="{{toggleDisable}}" />
```

#### JS

```
//code that sets `myFlag`. it works, so I have not posted it

$scope.toggleDisable = false;
$scope.checkType = function(){
   $scope.toggleDisable = $scope.myFlag ? true : false;
};
```

I can see `ng-disabled="{{toggleDisable}}"` changing in the dev tools from `true` to `false`, but the input always remains to the value I initially set it to.

Comment: `ng-disabled="toggleDisable"`

Comment: @Vineet Yes! Thank you!. The docs have the double braces ><

Comment: @zeroflagL Oops, right on. I was reading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try code as follows:

```
<input ng-disabled="toggleDisable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-change="checkType()" ng-options="sth in sth for things"></select>
<input ng-disabled="toggleDisable" />
```

remove the '{{}}'.

Check the docs for further info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled